# Convert Results<t> to [AnyObject]

Tags: ios, swift, realm

i'm using realm as a backend, however when i wanna show my realm in the following class i keep getting following error: `Cannot convert value of type Results<League> to expected argument type [AnyObject]]`?

do i need to map the result or what is my options?

```
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "#matches.@count > 0")
    menuArray = realm.objects(League).sorted("id").filter(predicate)
    let menuView = BTNavigationDropdownMenu(title: menuArray!.first!.name!, items: menuArray!)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = menuView
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a difference between a value of type `Results<Object>` (which is a custom Realm container type) and a value of type `[AnyObject]` (which is a Swift array of `AnyObject` objects), so you're probably right in thinking that you need to convert the result.

Try this:

```
let menuView = BTNavigationDropdownMenu(title: menuArray.first!.name!, items: menuArray.map { $0 })
```

This approach is probably OK in the context of a simple dropdown menu like the one you're using, but there may be a degradation in performance in other contexts.